# How does the mean momentum of a nucleon in a nucleus of mass number $A$ and atomic number $Z$ depends on $A$?

Tags: momentum, nuclear-physics, elements

I was going through a text and it said that

> The mean momentum $p$ of a nucleon in a nucleus of the mass number $A$ and atomic
> number $Z$ depends on $A$ as $$
> P\propto{A}^{-\frac{1}{3}}.
> $$

All that I know is that the radius of the nucleus is proportional to mass number as  $$
R \propto A^{\frac{1}{3}}.
$$ From here how can one relate momentum to the mass number? I would be grateful for even a hint.

Comment: I imagine this conclusion comes from treating the nucleus as the ground state of a Fermi gas.

Comment: Elsewhere on the internet someone had solved it using Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Comment: You can also do that, as long as you're comfortable with it not being a rigorous derivation. I'll post an answer along those lines below.

Comment: Thank you dear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an answer about nuclei with angular momentum. But the result also holds for spinless nuclei, because of the uncertainty principle. A particle that is somewhere within a box of size $R$ has position uncertainty $\sigma_x \sim R$, and therefore momentum uncertainty

$$ 
\sigma_p \gtrsim \hbar/R
$$

You can mess around with the factors of two if you like, but there's your one-squiggle proportionality relationship.

Comment: Thank you but this gives us the relationship between uncertainity of momentum radius and hence the mass number, how can i conclude from this that the average momentum obeys the same relationship?

Comment: The variance of a sampled quantity is the difference between the mean of the square and the square of the mean, $\sigma_p^2 = \left<p^2\right> - \left<p\right>^2$. In a stationary nucleus the average (vector) momentum $\left<p\right>$ is zero, so a typical "root-mean-square" magnitude $\sqrt{\left<p^2\right>}$ is the same as the standard deviation $\sigma_p$. Or put another way, if I told you that the momentum was $0\pm10$ and you measured the momentum directly, you would be unsurprised to measure $-8$ or $+12$ but surprised to measure $57$.

Comment: Thank you again Rob, this was immensely helpful. Just one more request. Since the mean momentum is zero and the text talks about the relationship of momentum and mass number, i guess the text means the RMS of momentum. What's your view on that.

Comment: Yes, the discussion is about a typical magnitude, irrespective of direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a *very* rough idea of the momentum scales that you would expect in the nucleus simply by using the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. Essentially, when you localize a particle such that its uncertainty in position is $\Delta x$, then its uncertainty in momentum $\Delta p$ is given by:

$$\Delta x\Delta p\gtrsim\frac{\hbar}{2}$$

(We use $\gtrsim$ rather than $\geq$ here because we're not quite localizing a particle to a particular 1-D box, or even to a 3-D cube; the nucleus is closer to a spherical well, and the operator structure is somewhat different. That said, it shouldn't be *too* different if we only want a very rough estimate. And really, all that matters for the purposes of our question is that the right-hand side is a constant.)

In the rest frame of the nucleus, the average momentum vector of a nucleon in the nucleus is zero, so the uncertainty in the momentum gives you a very rough measure of the *magnitude* of the momentum of the average nucleon. For $\Delta x$, we use the nuclear radius, which is roughly proportional to $A^{1/3}$. So, rearranging with $\Delta x\propto A^{1/3},$ we have that

$$\Delta p\propto \frac{1}{A^{1/3}}=A^{-1/3}$$

Comment: (+1) from me for your rigorous derivation! in my answer as well I used $R$ as a nuclear radius and the one who asked this my confirm that!

Comment: Thank you but this gives us the relationship between uncertainity of momentum with mass number, how can i conclude from this that the average momentum obeys the same relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple :

We have:
$$R \propto A^{\frac{1}3}$$
Which is exactly in my textbook:
$$R\approx1.4\times10^{-15}\sqrt[3]{A}$$
And the "angular momentum" is :
$$p=I\omega$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $\displaystyle \omega=\frac{v}R$
I think it's obvious now:
$$p\propto A^{-\frac{1}3}$$
Isn't it?

Comment: R is the radius of nucleus not the nucleon. So how can you substitute the radius of nucleus  in  $$
\omega
$$?

Comment: Also in the first formula, $R$ is the nucleon ray, go and search it! if you didn't find it email me at `elf12med@gmail.com` and I'll send you the part where it's mentioned!

Comment: nucleon ray?  I've never heard of that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @jmh the nucleon radius sorry! 

Comment: ok. sorry... i didn't think of that.

Comment: R is the nucleus radii unless A=1.  then its the nucleon radius.

Comment: @jmh No, I'm pretty sure that's $R$ is the nucleon radius, if you're insisting that means my book's wrong, can you give me a reference so I can confirm it?

Comment: what does the $A^{\frac{1}{3}}$ mean?  that a nucleon gets bigger and more nucleons are added?

Comment: when A =1 then 1.4 fermis = size of a nucleon.